# Java - synchronize

Tags: java, multithreading

I study synchronization for threads.
When I have this example:

```
class A {
  public synchronized void methodA(){

  }

  public synchronized void methodB(){

  }
}

class B {
  private final Object objectA = new Object(); 
  private final Object objectB = new Object();

  public void methodA(){
    synchronized(objectA){

    }
  }

  public void methodB(){
    synchronized(objectB){

    }
  }
}
```

Is correct that in first case all calls of both methods must be serialized? Methods can not be called concurrently and only one method from set of "synchronized" methods can be called at current time.

And in second case on level of object. Only one thread can call one method at current time. But methods A and B can be called concurrently?

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one thread can hold a lock on the object at the moment. For `class B` methods `methodA` and `methodB` use different objects for locking. So in the following code methods could be called by two different threads at the same time.

```
B b = new B();
Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {b.methodA()});
Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {b.methodB()});
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

But in `class A` you use `this` for locking. So in the following code calls will be serialized because only one thread could hold lock on object of class A. It happens because the same object is used as lock for both methods.

```
A b = new A();
Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {a.methodA()});
Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {a.methodB()});
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Comment: Good conclusion is that **each object has only one internal lock** and **lock can be held by only one thread**.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct on second part, but first part needs some clarification.

> ```
> class A {
>   public synchronized void methodA(){
>
>   }
>
>   public synchronized void methodB(){
>
>   }
> }
> ```

This code is do the same as next one

```
class A {
  public void methodA(){
       synchronized (this) {
       }
  }

  public void methodB(){
       synchronized (this) {
       }
  }
}
```

So on one object only one method can be called simultaneously. Other calls of the same or other method will wait. But on different objects any methods can be called.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `synchronized` takes effect when there are more than one `Thread` executing on the same objects.

In the first case only one `Thread` will be able to call `methodA` or `methodB` at a time. When one is executing the method the others will have to wait the method finishes.

In the second case, only one `Thread` will be able to enter each of the `synchronized` blocks at a time. The `synchronized` blocks are the ones inside the curly bracktes of

```
synchronized(objectA){

}
```

and

```
synchronized(objectA){

}
```